# MongoDB projection syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm writing a web application using NodeJs, and the most common syntax I use to project fields is:

```
db().collection("users").findOne(
    { name: "Igor" },
    { projection: { name: true, _id: false } }
);
```

It works well in the NodeJs environment. But then I was doing some checks through the shell, and this same query returns me an error:

```
//query
db.users.findOne({ name: "Igor" },{ projection:{ name: true, _id: false }})

//output
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Cannot do exclusion on field _id in inclusion projection",
    "code" : 31254,
    "codeName" : "Location31254"
}
```

Then, I tried to find references to `{projection: <field>: <true or false>}` without success. I also didn't have better luck researching the error. Then I thought it could be a method from the NodeJs Driver, but I also didn't find anything in the docs.

Another behavior is that when I try to project the name on the mongo shell, the result is only the document `_id`.

```
//query    
db.users.findOne({ name: "Igor" },{ projection:{ name: true }})

//output    
{ "_id" : ObjectId("607469840eaf9097e49c10c3") }
```

To be clear about what would be the expected result, I would achieve that result by writing the following query:

```
db.users.findOne({name: "Igor"},{ name: true, _id: false })
```

Could someone enlighten me where I could read more about this `projection` property? Or this a deprecated one that for some reason is still working?

Comment: post the reference link where you found `projection` property in find?

Comment: @turivishal I believe I found the answer.

**Doc**
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/interfaces/findoptions.html#projection

"The fields to return in the query. *Object of fields to either include or exclude* (one of, not both), {'a':1, 'b': 1} or {'a': 0, 'b': 0}."


And here is MongoDB's file which receives the object as an argument.

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/341a6026/src/operations/find.ts#L26

It doesn't work in the shell because it is a property only for the NodeJS Driver.

Answer (score 1):

The shell findOne method is documented here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Projection is the second positional argument, you are sending it as an options hash which is incorrect.

Comment: Thx for the answer @D.SM, but I was looking for more details about the `projection` property, from the MongoDB Nodejs driver. I found that and wrote about it in my comment above. In my question I even presented the right query which would lead to the proper output, respecting the shell findOne documentation: `db.users.findOne({name: "Igor"},{ name: true, _id: false })`

Comment: You are going back and forth between mongo shell and node driver. It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Photo.find({},{ book_id: 1, user_id: 1,  datetime: 1, userAgent: 1, createdAt: 1 })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.